# Bootstrap 4 tables not fits full width with d-flex

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, width, column-width

With the new Bootstrap 4 it's not possible anymore to simply apply classes like col-md-2 to the  or the  tags of a table.

So the solution seems to use class="d-flex" in the parent :

```
<tr class="d-flex">
```

but when I do it my whole table don't fit anymore in the parent div. And I can not do anything against it.

[image]

Can somebody help me to get the clue?

Here is the code of the table:

```
<div class="card-body">
   <h3 class="col-12 mt-2">Lehrer</h3>
   <table class="table table-light">
       <tbody>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="col-md-1">Florian</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">Wassermair</td>
                <td class="col-md-4">Schulbuchbeauftragter</td>

                <td class="col-md-1">
                   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/profile/show/4">
                      <i class="icon icon-eye"></i>
                   </a>
                </td>

                <td class="col-md-1">
                   <a class="btn btn-success" href="/personal/4/edit">
                       <i class="icon icon-edit"></i>
                   </a>
                </td>
           </tr>

           <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="col-md-1">Bernadette</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">Mayr</td>
                <td class="col-md-4"></td>

                <td class="col-md-1">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/profile/show/3">
                        <i class="icon icon-eye"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>

                <td class="col-md-1">
                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="/personal/6/edit">
                        <i class="icon icon-edit"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
           </tr>                                                                                         
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why d-flex and not row?

Comment: `col-*` are not meant to be used on table. If you really need to do so, use other container elements such as `div`. It is not a good practice either.

Comment: In bootstrap-4, either one of the columns should be `col` or  sum of the columns should be 12 to fill the row.

Comment: It does not matter, if it fit the 12 units. The whole table don't fit anymore to the parent div.

Comment: So if I don't have to use tables for this? What u would prefer? Divs? For what tables are for then? And even if u are right? There have to be a way to set up the width of every single column of a table... or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the table cells to fill the width, use 12 columns units...

```
<tr class="row mx-0">
    <td class="col-md-2">Bernadette</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">Mayr</td>
    <td class="col-md-6"></td>
    <td class="col-md-1">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/profile/show/3">
            <i class="icon icon-eye"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1">
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="/personal/6/edit">
            <i class="icon icon-pencil"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Or,** use `ml-auto` to push the columns to the right..

```
<tr class="row mx-0">
    <td class="col-md-2">Florian</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">Wassermair</td>
    <td class="col-md-4">Schulbuchbeauftragter</td>
    <td class="col-md-1 ml-auto">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/profile/show/4">
            <i class="icon icon-eye"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1">
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="/personal/4/edit">
            <i class="icon icon-pencil"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/xRodoKUKBf

Comment: Ok ... that surprised me. It actually works. Even without d-flex. Nice! 
But... the table is too long when I go to iPhone size and when I give the table the "table-responsive" - class. I have the same problem like before. So I think about using divs instead...